# c++ how add and use external so-library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have EUSignCP.so, I set it to /usr/local/lib/euscp/ and add to compiler line -L/usr/local/lib/euscp/, but when I try connect this lib #include "< EUSignCP >" get an error:

```
<EUSignCP>: No such file or directory
```

Please, help how correct connect and use external library

Comment: There are two parts. The headers and the library. The headers are used at compile time the library is used at compile and runtime. Did you install the headers in `/usr/local/include/euscp/ `?

Comment: but, if I have only EUSignCP.so?...

Comment: What is in `EUSignCP.so`? Is it C++ source code?

Comment: Without a header file your code does not know what is in the shared library so can not use any of its functionality.

Comment: And if I know what class has this library, I can call then without h-file (may be create it myself)?

Comment: That would be a bad idea (it is very likely to go wrong). There is more to it than simply knowing the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact the technical support of the library manufacturer JSC IIT (mailto: iit@iit.kharkov.ua or supp@iit.com.ua). The crypto library will be sent to you along with the header files.